# Can you do regression with jump-covariate?

Tags: predictor

I have a continuous predictor which looks like this:

```
x: 1, 2, 3, ...., 100, (!!) 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, ...., 399,  400, (!!) 700, 701, 702, 703, ....
```

As you can see, it "jumps". I have marked the jumps with (!!).

Is this never going to be an issue? Can I always model $y \sim x$, all else equal?

Comment: In  OLS, X is fixed so any values are fine. If you are confident of linearity, you can interpolate. Extrapolation is never wise.

Comment: What happens when you include a categorical variable to indicate the group?  Does that appreciably improve the fit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will matter, but it may be fine. When you plot y~x, do your y scores also have a 'jump'?  The linear relationship may be preserved overall.